# Error while adding event to google calendar - Insufficient Permission

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-calendar-api

I am trying to add event to google calendar with `.Net` Console App as a client. I am getting following error.

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError  Insufficient Permission [403] 
>   Errors [   Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ]
>   Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]  ]

on line

```
    service.Events.Insert(newEvent, "primary").Execute()
```

Here is my code

```
    Dim Scopes As String() = {CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly}
    Dim ApplicationName As String = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart"
    Dim credential As UserCredential
    Using stream = New FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets
        Dim credPath As String = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
        credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, "D:/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json")
        Dim dataStore = New FileDataStore(credPath, True)
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(clientSecrets, Scopes, "admin", CancellationToken.None, dataStore).Result
        Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " & credPath)
    End Using

    Dim service = New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = credential, .ApplicationName = ApplicationName})

    Dim newEvent As New Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event()
    Dim startDate As New EventDateTime
    Dim endtDate As New EventDateTime
    Dim scope =
    startDate.DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2)
    endtDate.DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(5)

    newEvent.Summary = "XYZ reminder"
    newEvent.Description = "Please contact dcsdc@cdscs.ss"
    newEvent.Start = startDate
    newEvent.End = endtDate
    newEvent.Id = "1122"


    Try
        service.Events.Insert(newEvent, "primary").Execute() 'Error here
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
```

However I am able to read events that are manually created using

```
Dim request As EventsResource.ListRequest = service.Events.List("primary")
```

**Also tried**

1. setting "user" in `AuthorizeAsync`.
2. setting email address as a calendarId in `service.Events.Insert`
3. setting scope as `Dim Scopes As String() = {CalendarService.Scope.Calendar}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your scope.

Dim Scopes As String() = {CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly}

You are allowed to read because your scope is CalendarReadonly.

However, to perform write operations like insert events, you need to use the read/write:

[Authorization](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

This request requires authorization with the following scope (read more about authentication and authorization).

**Scope**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
```

If it's not working when you changed the scope, keep in mind what the [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet) comment said:

> // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved
>   credentials
>           // at ~/.credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json

You modified the scope, you need to delete your previously saved credentials for the new scope to take effect.

Comment: I tried changing scope to `CalendarService.Scope.Calendar` but I will try to delete credentials and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: yep delete the old credentials

Comment: Now getting this error: Invalid resource id value. [400]

Comment: This means it worked. You have a different problem now which is related to you using wrong parameters to a given property. Open a new question and mark this answered. Let's see what we can do with your new problem. With regard to the "id" problem, try deleting that line, don't include it.